# Angular $watch not functioning when minified

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that implements the spin.js library. I use it to trigger a spinner that pops up when I transition pages. It watches a service function to know when to trigger the spinner. It works fine in development, but when I build the app using yeoman, the watch triggers when the page loads, but never again. Is there a different way to write the watcher so it works when minified? Maybe I'm missing something else here entirely...

```
var utilities = angular.module('SlUtilities', ['ui.router']);

utilities.directive('spinner', function ($window, spinner) {
  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {

      var window = angular.element($window);
      scope.spinner = null;

      function stopSpinner() {
        if (scope.spinner) {
          scope.spinner.stop();
          scope.spinner = null;
          element.hide();
        }
      }

      function startSpinner() {
        element.show();
        scope.spinner = new $window.Spinner(angular.fromJson(attr.spinner.replace(/'/g, '\"')));
        scope.spinner.spin(element[0]);
      }

      scope.$watch(spinner.spinning, function (start) {
        console.log(start);
        if (start) {
          startSpinner()
        } else {
          stopSpinner();
        }
      });

      scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        stopSpinner();
      });

      scope.style = function () {
        var top = window.height() / 2 - 35;
        var left = window.width() / 2 - 35;
        return {
          'top': top + 'px',
          'left': left + 'px'
        };
      }
    }
  };
});

//factory


utilities
  .factory('spinner', function () {

    var spin = false;

    // Public API here
    return {
      start: function () {
        spin = true;
      },
      stop: function () {
        spin = false;
      },
      spinning: function () {
        return spin;
      }
    };
  });
```

Excerpt from the minified code:

```
c.$watch(b.spinning,function(a){console.log(a),a?g():f()})
```

and

```
utilities.factory("spinner",function(){var a=!1;return{start:function(){a=!0},stop:function(){a=!1},spinning:function(){return a}}})
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `$watch variable` in quotes:

```
scope.$watch('spinner.spinning', function (start) {
```

And after minifying that would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Your Directive isn't compatible with minification.

you need to do the following as the watch seems ok

```
utilities.directive('spinner', ['$window', 'spinner', function ($window, spinner) {
  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {

      var window = angular.element($window);
      scope.spinner = null;

      function stopSpinner() {
        if (scope.spinner) {
          scope.spinner.stop();
          scope.spinner = null;
          element.hide();
        }
      }

      function startSpinner() {
        element.show();
        scope.spinner = new $window.Spinner(angular.fromJson(attr.spinner.replace(/'/g, '\"')));
        scope.spinner.spin(element[0]);
      }

      scope.$watch(spinner.spinning, function (start) {
        console.log(start);
        if (start) {
          startSpinner()
        } else {
          stopSpinner();
        }
      });

      scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        stopSpinner();
      });

      scope.style = function () {
        var top = window.height() / 2 - 35;
        var left = window.width() / 2 - 35;
        return {
          'top': top + 'px',
          'left': left + 'px'
        };
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```